# How to get rid infinitely small spaces after divisions?

Tags: svg, affinity-designer

I have been working on svg based design and I am having a problem with objects having infinitely small spaces between them after division by another object. This also gets rendered this way. I have always been solving it by increasing size of that object by moving it slightly, but this is far from an optimal solution. Is there something I can do to get rid of it or prevent it from happening?

Here it's visible on those separated circle parts, that have in most cases a small pink line between.
[image: Sample of this here]

Comment: Based on answers, I have merged those divided objects back together (using add method I created 3 colored rings) which did solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh yes pretty nasty conflation artifacts indeed.

You should boolean the white parts together. Anyway theres little you can do in the general case if you insist on having this kind of structure exact edges. Except perhaps if you want to render pixel images in which case you may supersample instead of using standard antialiasation.

Most vector rendering engines just simply compose the image wrong. We know the cause. We know how to make a software not do this*. But we choose to do nothing, mainly because it does not help if your rendering engine does it correctly if its going to be rendered by end user in a different engine.

* indeed 3D rendering engines have adressed this already in mid 1990's